# What's a simple algorithm for determining a falling/rising edge in a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm polling a simple sensor that can have a pretty sharp falling or rising edge; The values are being read back into a 1d std vector.

I don't want to just use a hard-coded trigger value since this isn't robust enough to accommodate different sensors that have different sensitivities and baseline values. I tried processing the vector through a low-pass filter but this distorted the signal enough that I no longer got a well defined edge.

I tried looking for the point where 6x the standard deviation of the previous samples exceeded the next sample, but this approach was highly susceptible to noise.

I'd appreciate any pointers out there!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Set threshold values for "too high to ignore" and "too low to ignore".  Ignore the values in the middle.  Only consider values as up or down when the threshold has been passed.  There is a name for this filter(Sobel?).  It escapes me at the moment.  Obviously, when you go from low to high, you have a rising edge; and when you go from high to low, you have a falling edge.